# SEF url and custom view

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component, view, jroute, router

Was able to create a custom component and a custom view which I went ahead and attached a js library to.
Now to achieve my desired functionality I need to create a custom url(SEF) in my route.php file, and attach a custom view to that route, then I can dynamically display content with url paramns, eg for ?id=1 view show

## ID = 1

. What way should I go ahead to defining a custom url and attaching a view to that page?

Comment: Welcome to JSE Nicholas.  Please take our [tour] to help you to become better acquainted with our community.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Nicholas and welcome!

You need to develop a custom router for your component. Have a look at https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component and the worked example in the MVC tutorial at https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_an_alias#Router_2 - that should be enough to get you going all the right lines.

Usually the ?id=1 in the URL gets replaced by something like /myitem in the SEF format, where "myitem" is the value you set in the alias field of your record with id=1.

You might then want to add an alias field in the record structure of your component, hence following that step in the MVC tutorial should be helpful.